# how to get data from listview

Tags: android

I've a listview and I want to get data from ArrayList when I click on an item but I don't know how can I do it:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            //what do i do
        }
    });
```

This way I get data:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("search");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
final JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    arrayList.add(new resultsearch(
         object1.getInt("id"),
         object1.getString("destination"),
         object1.getString("infor"),
         object1.getString("city"),
         object1.getInt("rating"),
         object1.getString("img"),
         BigDecimal.valueOf(object1.getDouble("point")).floatValue(),
         object1.getString("comments")
         ));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `position` argument of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` to get access to your data at any specific position.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = adapter.getItem(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have entries inside your list. I think your List inside the adapter will be the `arrayList`. So the position inside the `arraylist` is the position of the item you clicked on.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
        arraylist.get(position);
    }
});
```

I don't know what kind of an object you have here: So it will be something like: `Object yourObject = arraylist.get(position);`

Or as mentioned in comments by Karim. Get the item over the adapter `adapter#getItem(position)`!

Comment: This is one way to do it but I prefer not using the `arrayList` because sometimes the data in the adapter is not in sync with `arrayList`.  I prefer `adapter#getItem(position)`.

Comment: Thats right! Your way is better! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to get data from ArrayList inside the OnitemClickListener method is,

```
bookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String bookName = booksArrayList.get(position);
        }
    });
```

With `get` method you get the value at index `position` in your array List.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have all the getters in the ResultSearch class

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
        String information;
        ResultSearch resultSearch = arrayList.get(position);
        information = new StringBuilder()
        .append("id: " + resultSearch.getInt("id") + "\n")
        .append("destination: " + resultSearch.getString("destination") + "\n")
        .append("infor: " + resultSearch.getString("infor") + "\n")
        .append("city: " + resultSearch.getString("city") + "\n")
        .append("rating: " + resultSearch.getInt("rating") + "\n")
        .append("img: " + resultSearch.getString("img") + "\n")
        .append("point: " + resultSearch.getDouble("point") + "\n")
        .append("comments: " + resultSearch.getString("comments") + "\n")
        .toString();
        //display this using an AlertDialog or open an activity containing this information
    }
});
```